# geting xml element attr value using child attr entered in textbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, xpath

this is my XML file:-

```
<products>
  <product_id value="1">
    <tab_id value="351">
      <tab_name value="test1" />
      <region_timezone value="1" />
      <registrationstatus value="2" />
      <eventstatus value="2" />
      <dist_activity value="5,10068,10070" />
      <reg_str_dt value="2013-01-14 20:35:00" />
      <reg_end_dt value="2013-01-14 20:35:00" />
    </tab_id>
  </product_id>
  <product_id value="2">
    <tab_id value="352">
      <tab_name value="test2" />
      <region_timezone value="1" />
      <registrationstatus value="2" />
      <eventstatus value="2" />
      <dist_activity value="5,10069,10070" />
      <reg_str_dt value="2013-02-14 20:39:00" />
      <reg_end_dt value="2013-02-14 20:39:00" />
    </tab_id>
  </product_id>
</products>
```

this is Function:-

```
function get_list(){
    xmlDoc = $.parseXML( xml ),
    $xml = $( xmlDoc ),
    $title = $xml.find('[value="'+$('#select').val()+'"] *');
    var str='';
    $title.each(function(){
        str+=$(this).attr('value')+' ';
    });
    $("#result").html(str);
}
```

this is Html Code:-

```
<input type="text" id="select">
<input type="button" name="button" value="Search" onclick="get_list()" >
<div id="result">
</div>
```

here i have one Text box
Entered in textbox any of the child attr value of xml file EG:-

```
first text box:- Dist_activity(tag name)
second textbox:- 5(attr value)
```

and then click on button it search and display first Element value EG:-

```
in div "Result":- 1(is product_id value)
```

here its possible to using xpath and xquery then best for me other are also.
thanks...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about something like this:

```
<html>
<head>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        var xml;
        $.get(
        "SOXml_Converted.xml",
        null,
        function (data) {
            xml = data;
        },
        "xml"
    );
        function get_list() {
            var elName = $('#select').val();
            var value = $('#value').val();
            var xPath = '//*[local-name() = "' + elName + '" and ' +
                            ' contains(concat(@value, ","), "' + value  + ',")]' + 
                            '/../../@value';


            var iterator = xml.evaluate(xPath, xml.documentElement, null,
                XPathResult.UNORDERED_NODE_ITERATOR_TYPE, null);
            var thisNode = iterator.iterateNext();
            var str = '';
            while (thisNode) {
                if (str) {
                    str += ', ';
                }
                str += thisNode.textContent;
                thisNode = iterator.iterateNext();
            }

            $("#result").text(str);
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <input type="text" id="select">
    <input type="text" id="value">
    <input type="button" name="button" value="Search" onclick="get_list()">
    <div id="result">
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Of course, that won't locate anything with the values "Dist_activity" and "5", because there's no element with the name "Dist_activity" and there isn't even a `dist_activity` element with the value 5.

Comment: thanks but i dont know i am going right or not please check my answer what i do wrong??

Comment: @user2122438 I fixed some issues that were in your code and mine.  Could you give the above a try?

Comment: hmmmm good but i need one more step in them how return first element attribute value eg:- with this o/p return tab_id but i want to product_id attribute value (y) thanks for this answer its solve my much problem

Comment: now just one little bit query we enter attr value in second textbox in my xml file some tag contain 3 attribute value like dist_activity 5,10068,10070 if we enter those three at a time in textbox then its  work  here i need any of the attr bute value i have enter any one of them like 10068 then also allow and display o/p

Comment: great now i have one more requests but first i will try my self as possible if not success then need your help   thanks

Comment: and again salute for this work you are a god of xml and xpath (y)

Answer (score 0):

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
var xml;
$.get(
    "xml_converted.xml",  
    function(data) { xml=data; },
    "html"
);
function get_list(){
    var xPath = '//*[local-name() = "' + $('#select').val() + '" and @value = "' +
            $('#value').val() + '"]/..';
var iterator = document.evaluate(xPath, documentNode, null, 
                XPathResult.UNORDERED_NODE_ITERATOR_TYPE, null );
var thisNode = iterator.iterateNext();
var str = '';
while (thisNode) {
   str += thisNode.textContent ;
   thisNode = iterator.iterateNext();
 } 

    $("#result").html(str);
}
</script>

</head>
<input type="text" id="select">
<input type="text" id="value">
<input type="button" name="button" value="Search" onclick="get_list()" >
<div id="result">
</div>
</html>
```